# ¿Cómo puedo configurar un Timeout dentro de un .map?

Tags: javascript, map, timeout

tengo una problema, tengo esto y no se como hacerles returns con intervalos de tiempo

```
[{ fruit: banana, duration: 4s}, { fruit: apple, duration: 8s}, { fruit: orange, duration: 1s}]
```

Necesito hacerle un .map y no entiendo como hacer poner el intervalo de tiempo correspondiente.

Quedaria asi el resultado esperado:

```
Banana (4segundos)
Apple (8 Segundos)
Orange (1 Segundo)
```

Estoy usando react para poder hacer esto, si podria aplicar a un componente en general mejor, la idea es cambiar la imagen de a cuerdo con la fruta.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código que has intentado? Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Edita el título al español :D

Answer (score 0):

Sería bueno que mostraras el código para tener un poco más de claridad de lo que quieres hacer y poderte decir que estas haciendo mal, sin embargo, supongo que estas teniendo problema porque en el callback de la función map llamas al setTimeout que ejecuta asincronamente y por tanto en cada iteración del map no se ha resuelto el resultado del setTimeout.

Asumo que quieres hacer algo así

```
var frutasList = [{ fruit: "banana", duration: 4000}, { fruit: "apple", duration: 8000}, { fruit: "orange", duration: 1000}]
var frutas = [];
frutasList.forEach(i => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        frutas = [ ...frutas, i ];
        console.log(frutas);
    }, i.duration)
});
```

Donde tengo dos arreglos uno con el listado que tienes de frutas **frutasList** y los recorro cada uno para ir agregando al arreglo **frutas**. Hago una impresión por consola para que puedas ver el resultado en el orden y tiempo que quieres.

Por tanto, solo sería necesario que usaras la variable **frutas** en el render del componente react que quieras elaborar.

Comment: Me gustaria hacerlo con un .map para recorrer todo intente esto pero no pude hacerlo

Comment: Pero el forEach también lo recorre todo y ejecuta una función para cada item, con la diferencia que no retorna nada. Y si en lugar de una variable vas agregandolos al state del componente para que al cambiar el state se ejecute el renderizado nuevamente